# Firebase API initialization is failing on startup

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library, firebase-analytics, support-v4

On app startup, the following is being printed to the console:

```
Firebase API initialization failure.                                                        
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
   //..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg'
```

Firebase setup was done following the instructions:

1. `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` was added to top level `build.gradle`
2. `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` was added to app level `build.gradle`

Running `./gradlew app:dependencies`, I can see the following output:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0
          |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.0
          |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
          \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.0.0
               +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0
               |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
               |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0 (*)
               |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.0 (*)
               +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
               +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.0.0
               |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0 (*)
               |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0 (*)
               \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0 (*)
```

Perhaps it's part of the issue, perhaps not, but I find it odd that the latest version of the plugin includes an older version of Firebase (`9.0.0`) instead of `11.0.1`.

Also, as the error states, the issue is caused by the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()'
```

This seems to suggest that the v4 support library may be relevant to the issue.

What is causing these problems, and what's the solution?

Comment: Are you sure you compiled Firebase 11.0.1?

Comment: @cricket_007 What? The `google-services` plugin includes the library, and as seen in the output of `./gradlew app:dependencies`, it adds the `9.0.0` version.

Comment: The plugin adds analytics to your classpath. It does not compile any other part of Firebase into your actual app

Comment: Please reread the issue.

Comment: I did read the issue. Please reread the Firebase docs and notice `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'`

Comment: The core and several other libraries are included in the plugin. Explicitly depending on the core is not required.

Comment: But if you do not, then it will use version 9.0.0, as you can see... All I am suggesting is that you at least try to compile the later versions

Answer (score 1):

When I run the dependencies task, with no Google Play or Firebase libraries specified as dependencies in the app module `build.gradle`, I see this warning message at the top of the output produced:

```
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
```

Scroll that message right to see: `default version: 9.0.0 will be used`

The reason the plugin must be applied **after** the dependencies block in the `build.gradle` is that it scans the list of libraries to determine what version to use for it's processing.  Your module dependencies must include at least one Firebase or Google Play library so the plugin can choose a version number.

You indicate in a comment to your post that *Explicitly depending on the core is not required*.  Is that in the documentation somewhere?  Looking at the Setup Guides for the each of Firebase APIs ([Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/), Realtime Database, Storage, Crash Reporting, etc), each of them includes a step to add that API's library to the dependencies.

Comment: If you click to add an Android application to your Firebase project, it launches a modal walking you through the steps. The final step instructs the developer to include `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` in their top level `build.gradle` and to apply the plugin in their app level `build.gradle`. It then mentions that Analytics is included by default and shows no need to include any other dependencies.

Comment: Note, explicitly adding `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'` to my dependecies does bump up the version as shown in the output of `./gradlew app:dependencies`. However, while this does alleviate the original error, there is now an odd issue occuring where my presenter's call to `getView()`, which in this case is an Activity, is returning null. Removing Firebase resolves this issue, which I find odd. This issue isn't necessarily associated with this question, so I'll likely submit another.